# How do I plot just the residuals in plotly or ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, plotly, linear-regression

If I want to plot just the residuals, I can do

```
plot(model$residuals)
```

and I will get a nice scatter plot. how do I do the same in ggplot2 or plotly?
I don't want to plot resid vs fitted values.

thanks,
Adi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps like this?

```r
model <- lm(Sepal.Width ~ Petal.Length, data = iris)

ggplot(data.frame(x = seq(model$residuals), y = model$residuals)) +
  geom_point(aes(x, y)) +
  labs(x = "Index", y = "Residuals", 
       title = paste("Residuals of", format(model$call)))
```

[image: ![enter image description here]

Which is a bit nicer than:

```r
plot(model$residuals)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Similar to @AllanCameron you can use `broom` package that also offers other options about results from a model (variables in `df`):

```
library(ggplot2)
library(broom)
#Data
data("iris")
#Model
m1 <- lm(Sepal.Length~Sepal.Width,data=iris)
df <- augment(m1)
ggplot(df, aes(x = 1:nrow(df), y = .resid)) + geom_point() + xlab('x')
```

[image]